# Adding netty-socketio to Play Framework 2 for Socket.IO support

Tags: maven, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to add netty-socketio (https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) to a Play Framework 2.2 project. I added the following line to build.sbt, inside libraryDependencies:

"com.corundumstudio.socketio" %% "netty-socketio" % "1.6.2",

However when I compile, it can't find the library and gives the following error:

sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.corundumstudio.socketio#netty-socketio_2.10;1.6.2: not found

I think I have to add a resolver and what's the URL for that or is there any other way around?

I also thought adding the Jar directly what it has many other dependencies so I don't want to do that.

Comment: Use the latest version of netty-socketio - 1.6.5

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using `%%` instead of `%`. Both of these exist, but they are different. When you use `%%`, the Scala version is appended to the package name. (See "com.corundumstudio.socketio#netty-socketio_**2.10**;1.6.2:" in the error message.) In general, `%%` is used for Scala dependencies, while `%` is used for other dependencies. So you should rather write:

```
"com.corundumstudio.socketio" % "netty-socketio" % "1.6.2",
```

Note that I am not sure if it can be easily integrated it with Play.